# How to provide all route params to getStaticPaths?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to create a dynamic page component [page].js that can display pages dynamically. The route is set dynamically to

***`localhost:3000/[channel]/[store]/page/[slug]`***

I provided `slug` as params in paths array in `getStaticPaths` but I'm getting the following error:

> Server Error
> *Error: A required parameter (channel) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /[channel]/[store]/page/[slug]*
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

It looks like it's asking for `channel` and `store` params?

I do have `channel` and `store` data in `getStaticProps` but not in `getStaticPaths`.

I've set up `getStaticPaths` with `slug` param but I'm not sure how to find out `channel` and `store` params here.

```
import {fetchLayout} from "../../../../http/server/fetchLayout";
import Layout from "../../../../views/layout/Layout/Layout";
import Head from "../../../../resources/components/Head/Head";
import {fetchPage} from "../../../../http/server/fetchPage";
import {fetchPages} from "../../../../http/server/fetchPages";

const Page = ({ layout, page }) =>
{
    if ( page && layout ) {
        const { title, meta_title, description, keywords } = page
        return (

            <Layout data={ layout }>

                <Head title={ meta_title } >
                    <meta name="description" content={ description } />
                    <meta name="keywords" content={ keywords } />
                </Head>

                <h1 style={{ textAlign: `center`, margin: `50px 0` }}>{ title }</h1>

            </Layout>

        )
    }
    return null
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) =>
{
    const layout = await fetchLayout()
    // const { channel, store } = layout.region 
    const page = await fetchPage( params.slug )
    return { props: { layout, page }}
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () =>
{
    const pages = await fetchPages()
    const paths = pages.map(({ slug }) => ({ params: { slug }}))

    return { paths, fallback: true }
}

export default Page
```

Comment: Can you not call `fetchLayout` in `getStaticPaths` and pass the `channel` and `store` params in the `paths` array?

Comment: Thank you! yes, that's doable but that would make two exactly same requests for a single page. Is there a better workaround for this?

Comment: If you call `fetchLayout` in `getStaticPaths` and pass the values as params, do you even need to call it again in `getStaticProps`?